# no display at installing time

Tags: 18.04, brightness

I have a pc in which I am able to use Ubuntu then I buy a laptop and
when I try to install ubuntu in my laptop there is a black screen but when I use a flashlight on my laptop screen then I barely able to see a menu which asks to try or install
I get this same problem with Kali Linux also

system: ASUS rog gl503vd

Comment: Have you tried increasing the screen brightness?

Comment: yes, but it's not increasing

Comment: Try setting it in the BIOS/UEFI settings (entered usually by pressing F2 or F8 during boot), and disable any "auto brightness" setting if it is there.

Comment: I already tried it, but there is no option to change the brightness

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1_AgAp416UTW2VYB9UF0i93MwWdf7mm0B/view